# Nodejs equivalent of sending one GET request to the server to fetch data from the API

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the API endpoint where I am trying to get the data from `https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1`.

When I run this in the browser or in the Postman, I get a successful response. This is expected output snippet.

> {   "standard" : {      "addresst" : {},      "city" : "Warsaw",
>   "prov" : "PL",      "countryname" : "Poland",      "postal" : {},
>   "confidence" : "0.7"   },   "longt" : "21.03539",   "alt" : {
>   "loc" : {         "longt" : "21.23400",         "prov" : "PL",
>   "city" : "Warsaw",         "countryname" : "Poland",         "postal"
>   : "05-077",         "region" : {},         "latt" : "52.21890"      } 
>   },   "elevation" : {},   "latt" : "52.23275"}

I am trying to get the same output using nodejs. I tried the default https and request module but of no avail. This is what I have:

```
const request = require('request');

request('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body);
});
```

This is the output I am seeing:

> { success: false,   error: { code: '006', message: 'Request
>   Throttled.' } }

The API for the free version expects just 1 request per second.

> Throttled API access is free. Rate limit: up to 1 API call per sec.
>   API (Throttled to no more that 1 request per second for all free port
>   users combined. eg., if 2 free requests come at the same time, each
>   gets throttled to 2 seconds per request).

How do I limit my code to send just one request? How am I able to get a response while using browser/postman. How do I achieve the same expected, successful response using nodejs?

This is also what I tried using https and I got the same response:

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: Where is that piece of code running? Is it on a VPS? Do you share the IP with anyone else besides you? You should be able to get that one successful request per second before beind throttled.

Comment: No, its not on VPS. Yes, I am trying to figure out how to limit to just one request and I don't understand why multiple requests are needed or sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Geocode.xyz doc](https://geocode.xyz/api)

> (...) no more than 1 request per second for **all un-authenticated users combined**

You have to create an account, get an API key and use it. Your issue should be solved.

You have 10 requests/s free plan.

Comment: Thanks, Although, I don't understand how or why it works in case of postman/browser without using api key

Comment: Probably some kind of internal system to prevent from spamming. But yeah, it's weird..

Comment: Yup works now. I had to replace `https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1` with `https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1&auth=Authcode`